# cordova/phonegap youtube api v3 what key type to use

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, youtube-data-api

I'm creating a **cordova/phonegap** iOS app which uses the **Youtube API v3** for searching.

What **type and origin** should I use for getting OAuth Client ID and API key from code.google.com/console?

I've tried:

- Type ios: using Bundle ID = *com.myappname.app* --> got authen error
- Type other: --> got authen error
- Type web browser: *what origin??*

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use a Simple API Key access (not OAuth) to make a request for public videos searching via Youtube API.

How to use API Key
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#LoadinganAPIandMakingaRequest